# Do the ROM files contain some information about themselves?

Tags: custom-roms, system-info

I have downloaded so many custom ROMs to try, but I did not organize them. One of the zip files is called "ODEXED.zip".

Is there any way to determine what it's name is just by inspecting the files in the zip file? Or maybe some other information about it?

This is just curiosity, I know I can just flash it and see its info in "Settings>About Phone".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. I have found the answer, at least for that ROM:

In the `/system/build.prop` file in the zip file, the first "section" has build properties, which details all the information that is visible in the "About Phone" part.

This is an example of it here:

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=GINGERBREAD
ro.build.display.id=Hyper_Droid
ro.build.version.incremental=DDKT3
ro.build.version.sdk=10
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=2.3.6
ro.build.date=Wed Feb  1 15:11:04 KST 2012
ro.build.date.utc=1328076664
[...]
ro.product.brand=samsung
ro.product.model=GT-S5670
ro.product.name=GT-S5670
ro.product.device=GT-S5670
ro.product.board=GT-S5670
ro.modversion= v2.0
ro.author.name= Wilfred
[...]
# end build properties
#
# system.prop for GT-S5670
#
```

Comment: That's exactly where you need to go, for every ROM.

Comment: @HamedMomeni Ok, thanks. I asked the question too soon, but now at least it will benefit others :)

Comment: @jadkik94 Feel free to "Accept" your own answer, so that others searching the site can see that it's been resolved.

Comment: @Chahk Done, I had to wait 2 days before I could do it, SE policy :)